# Linux 4.19: apply devicetree overlay on live system

Tags: linux, device-tree, overlayfs

Is it possible to apply a devictree overlay on a live system? We have an embedded system that has some optional hardware. We would like to load the devicetree information after Linux booted.

Reqaon for this: our additional hardware uses a I2C bus to configure itself created by another component on an SPI bus. Unfortunate, the communication between our cpu and optional hardware is going over SPI.

Since a devicetree is "worked off" in chronological order, we cannot "go back" to the SPI bus after initializing our I2C bus.

I already tried to mount configfs, did not work and is not recommended in prouction environments.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This works (me trying to enable video on an rpi4):

```
# mkdir /sys/kernel/config/device-tree/overlays/vc4-fkms-v3d/

# cat vc4-kms-v3d.dtbo > /sys/kernel/config/device-tree/overlays/vc4-fkms-v3d/dtbo

# cat /sys/kernel/config/device-tree/overlays/vc4-fkms-v3d/status
applied
```